# django-imagekit compress image if image size is GT 300KB

Tags: python, django, image, django-imagekit

I have managed to install (after a lot of effort) [django-imagekit](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and I am now able to use [django-imagekit](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to compress the file size of uploaded images.

I can upload an image of 6MB and [django-imagekit](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will compress the image to 230KB when I use a quality of 10 (see below).

**Is there a way to use a different file compression (django-imagekit refers to this as quality) when the uploaded image is a size of 300Kb, 1MB , 2MB, 3MB or larger (I am thinking an if/elseif/else statement that would confirm the size of the image and apply a lower quality the larger the size (KB) of the image?** The file compression of 10 works well for larger sized images but radically degrades the quality of the image for smaller sized images for example 25Kb.

I am not even sure how I would write the code and where I would place the code that would achieve this. So any help would be appreciated.

Here is my relevant models.py file code:

```
from imagekit.processors import Adjust, ResizeToFill
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField

class NameDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ....
    #name_details_photograph = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_name_details_photograph_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    name_details_photograph = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=_get_name_details_photograph_upload_location, null=True, blank=True, options={'quality': 25}, processors=[Adjust(sharpness=1.1),])
    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried to implement the form field version of the ProcessedImageField class, but this does not upload the image.

Here is the forms code I have tried while changing the models.py code back to a image field (that is commented out above):

```
from imagekit.forms import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import Adjust, ResizeToFill

class NameDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, available_languages, language_preference, file_required, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        available_languages should be a valid choices list
        """
        super(NameDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['language_code'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=available_languages, initial=language_preference, label=_('Language'),)
        #self.fields['name_details_photograph'] = forms.FileField(label=_('Photograph'), required=file_required)
        self.fields['name_details_photograph'] = ProcessedImageField(label=_('Photograph'), required=file_required, spec_id='myapp:profile:name_details_photograph', options={'quality': 25}, processors=[Adjust(sharpness=1.1),])

    class Meta:
        model = NameDetails
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution I'm gonna offer is totally untested. It's based on the source code of the [`imagekit`](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/tree/develop/imagekit) library.

The `options` `kwarg` is used by the [`ImageSpec`](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#defining-specs-outside-of-models) class to passe it to PIL's `Image.save()`.

So for a dynamic `options` you can create your own `Spec` class defining `options` as a `property` and use the `getter` to return an on-the-fly `options`. Something like:

```
from imagekit import ImageSpec
from imagekit.processors import Adjust, ResizeToFill

class ThumbnailSpec(ImageSpec):
    format = 'JPEG'
    options={'quality': 50}
    processors=[Adjust(sharpness=1.1),]

    @property
    def options(self):
        options = self._options
        #You can create some checks here and choose to change the options
        #you can access the file with self.source
        if self.source.size > 2*100*100:
            options['quality'] -= 25
        return options
    @options.setter
    def options(self, value):
        self._options = value
```

Finally use your `ThumbnailSpec` by passing it to the `ProcessedImageField`

```
name_details_photograph = ProcessedImageField(
    upload_to=_get_name_details_photograph_upload_location, 
    null=True, 
    blank=True, 
    spec=ThumbnailSpec
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom [processor](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#processors) with `django` `imagekit` and then use it in your model. The [processor](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#processors) will check the size of the image and then return the edited image. Something like this -

```
class ConditionalResizer(object):
    min_size = None  # minimum size to reduce in KB
    def __init__(self, *args, min_size=1000, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) # code is for python > 3.0, modify for python < 3.0 as necessary 
        self.min_size = min_size

    def process(self, image):
        size = # code to get size of image
        if size > self.min_size:
            # process the image
            image = # processed image
        return image
```

Then in your `Form`, add the processor -

```
from imagekit.forms import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import Adjust, ResizeToFill

class NameDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, available_languages, language_preference, file_required, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    available_languages should be a valid choices list
    """
    super(NameDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['language_code'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=available_languages, initial=language_preference, label=_('Language'),)
    #self.fields['name_details_photograph'] = forms.FileField(label=_('Photograph'), required=file_required)
    self.fields['name_details_photograph'] = ProcessedImageField(label=_('Photograph'), required=file_required, spec_id='myapp:profile:name_details_photograph', options={'quality': 25}, processors=[Adjust(sharpness=1.1), ConditionalResize(min_size=1000)])

class Meta:
    model = NameDetails
```

I haven't tested this code yet, but should be able to solve your problem. Let me know if it does not.

You can find more about processors here - https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#processors